# Is there a way to have a database with face ids (apple) to use for multiple users biometric auth?

Tags: ios, database

I am not familiar with iOS dev, so I am not sure if I am bound by the only two different face ids an iPad has.

I understand that those are for unblocking the device, but would it be possible to use that functionality to check the "check-ins and outs" of a number of employees?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The local authentication framework (FaceID and TouchID) doesn't provide any information on which biometric item was presented, only a yes/no as to whether a valid authentication occurred.  You cannot use FaceID to identify a specific user.

Comment: That I was afraid of. But this class really got me wondering:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avmetadatafaceobject/face_metadata_type 
Anyhow thanks a lot Paul!

Comment: Refer to clause 2.5.13 of the developer review guidelines https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirements